Font overflow issue with AnnotatingString in Jetpack Compose
Has anyone faced an issue with a Font like on picture below that represents a text with a font, for some reason, some characters go back to the line even though the text is set on (no idea why it overflows).

softWrap = false,
overflow = TextOverflow.Visible,

since it was somehow an overflow I even tried this:
onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
    while (textLayoutResult.hasVisualOverflow) {
        println("has overFlow")
        annotatedStringDFontSize -= 1f
    }
}


but nothing it just keeps on printing overflow, I even tried to only set the first word but somehow its still got an overflow.
If I apply maxLines = 1, then the characters will be invisible:

If I use another font the default font for example it works fine without even including maxLines = 1:
.

Please [edit] your question and add a [mre].
